# custom tailwind css works fine on html tag but core tailwind class does not work

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I setup tailwind css and nextjs. when custom classes on global.css is applied on html tags it work but when tailwind classes are applied directly on html tags it does not work

```
const page = () => {
    return (
        <div className="flex">
            <div className='register'>
                <h3 className='text-blue-600'>Signup Form</h3>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div className='register'>
                <h3 className='text-blue-600'>Signup Form</h3>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

global.css

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

.register {
  @apply bg-red-500;
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  purge: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

register works fine but text-blue-600 does not work

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

My file structure

[image]

Comment: Could you provide your `postcss.config.js` content please? Could you also confirm the version of the `tailwindcss` package you have installed?

Comment: @Wongjn I installed version 3

Comment: Are you importing the CSS in your `_app.js` file (`import '@styles/globals.css'`)?

Comment: FYI, the config option `purge` was removed in Tailwind v3. See: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6019